# Why ride a single-speed bike?

Tags: single-speed

A question came up recently about [why people ride fixed-gear bikes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/why-ride-a-fixed-gear-bike). I think you can't reasonably answer that question without first understanding why people ride **single-speed** bikes.

So, why do they do it?

Comment: I'm assuming we'll talk about leg strength, simplicity, memories of bikes from childhood, etc., but I'll let someone else write a good answer & get the rep.

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing! I have been reading fatty's blog http://www.fatcyclist.com/ and it appears that he rides a single speed most of the time.

Comment: Great answers so far but I am hoping we also get an answer from someone who rides single speeds in races and endurance rides.

Comment: @Mike I'd ride a single speed in a race or endurance ride for the same reason I ride one the rest of the time. The achievement value, simplicity, and fun.

Comment: I'm going to be a jerk and give the "true" two valid reasons. One, you care more about style than functionality. In other words, you're a hipster. Two, you are legitimately involved in track cycling. That means you're not a doofus riding a brakeless track bike around NYC streets.

Comment: @Apreche - Why are you profiling fixed/single riders? I am all about functionality over style and ride a fixie. Just because that would be your motivation (and is quite possibly the motivation for others) don't assume that it's the case for everyone.

Comment: I appreciate both sides of this argument, This is why I need three geared bikes and two single speed bikes. If the weather is perfect and I am riding a distance of 50km or more, I will take my sweetest bike , a full carbon / ultegra bike kept in my basement. If the wheather is less than perfect my plan B bike is a aluminuim with carbon fork / campy groupset bike for those distances. In the snow I use heavy mountain bike, I have a very "nice" Single Speed for use around my neighborhood, and to occasionaly train on local hills, and my "beater" single speed is a utility bike for anything else (an

Comment: I would say if you have a fine and straight line path throughout your region, a fixie is good. Having gear is a plus when you go uphill. I have used both and saying this from my experience.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I ride a single-speed (as opposed to fixed gear) because I like to be able to coast down a hill without worrying about spinning out, or hitting a pot-hole while frantically trying to keep up with my pedals. Don't get me wrong, I love riding fixed-gear, but for where I live it's just a little impractical to not be able to coast.

I ride a single-speed (as opposed to a geared bike) for multiple reasons.

A: It's all I could afford. If you only have $600, you'll get a lot more bike with a single-speed than a geared bike.  Or rather, you'll get a lighter bike with better hubs/wheels/etc than for a $600 geared bike. Someday I'll have the money for a decent road bike (105/Rival or better) and will buy one. But for now, my single-speed is much lighter and sturdier than any $600 geared road bike I could have gotten.

B: I enjoy the simplicity. Want to go faster? Pedal faster.

C: I enjoy the workout. I live in Utah, where there are some pretty big hills/mountains. The only way to get to the top is to (as my dad used to say) hunker down and gut it out. There's something quite invigorating about knowing you conquered that hill with the power in your legs instead of the mechanical advantage of your gear ratio.

D: Even on the freewheel side of my hub, my single-speed is *quiet*. No gears means that unless I'm coasting, my bike is nearly silent.

Comment: I like the loud pawl click of a cassette hub.

Comment: Me too. I also like that while I'm pedaling I'm in stealth mode, and then when I start to coast the load clack-clack of my freewheel surprises people. (although I try to be polite most of the time)

Comment: Reminds me of the Schwinn Stingray I got in '78 for my birthday. A fine bike, that one. Banana seat, red/yellow paint scheme.

Comment: A is a quite good reason, I also ride a single speed and that's mainly because everything is easier: cheaper and easier maintenance (most of the time you don't to go to a bikeshops) and better bike for a smaller price. Also D is great, I still amaze myself by how silent my bike is when I'm riding alone.

Comment: The question is not why one chooses to ride single speed over a fixed gear bicycle but why one chooses to ride a single speed (presumably over a geared bicycle).

Answer (score 22):

Back in the thirties, Tullio Campagnolo invented the modern derailleur for very good reason.

A single-speed is a very sensible machine if the terrain and/or rider strength allow.  Simple, reliable, lightweight.
But for many, not a practical solution. If widely varying terrain must be tackled, the single speed is going to be problematic.
The objections given to multiply-geared bikes are valid, but a well-maintained gear train is essentially silent, reliable, and easy to use.
I'm a mechanic, and my bikes shift effortlessly and positively.  I "stir" my gears constantly to keep my pedal pressure and cadence at an optimum.  I enjoy doing this, much as sports-car drivers enjoy a manual transmission.

As for fixies... Used to be a standard training item for pro road racers.  The idea being to build up both leg strength, spin, and smoothness.
However, I think a fixie, especially one without modern brakes is as dangerous to ride now as it was at the dawn of cycling back in the 1800s.
I see it as a fad item.

Comment: Has been flagged for length and content. But it does state “simple, reliable, lightweight”, 3 positives for SS, and 16 people upvoted so far, there’s an answer in there. Looks Ok

Answer (score 18):

It is less expensive and it has less parts that can break and almost no fragile parts compared to bikes with more gears. This means:

- I can leave it outside in the rain without feeling guilty
- It will last for years with nearly no maintenance
- I can park it outside a bar with a decent lock on it and it will still be there when I stagger out at the end of the evening.
- I can park it in the bicycle chaos at the local train station and not mind the scratches.
- Save for the occasional flat it always works

That said: If I lived anywhere where the were hills higher than the bridges over the canals I would probably never use it.

p.s. I have something like this only mine is (and looks) about 30 years old (the frame anyway):

[image: omafiets]

Answer (score 15):

I rode nothing but a single speed (as opposed to fixed gear) 24" Bontrager Cruiser (like a big BMX) for approx 8 years and loved it.  Daily commute (~10-15Km round trip) and most other incidental/social travel.  I have only recently changed to a 8 speed [Charge Tap](http://www.chargebikes.com/products/bikes/detail.php?id=26) due to moving to a very hilly neighborhood.

For me, the beauty of single speed is the simplicity.  *@Jay Bazuzi called it ; )*

No worrying about what gear I should be in.  Just stand up and pedal harder.
No worrying about gears slipping or being tuned properly.  Chain tight, done.
No worrying  about which brake lever to pull and how hard.  Only had one to choose from.

I also loved the feeling of being more 'connected' to the road than on a geared bike.  (I've never owned a fixie but I'm told they feel even more 'connected' than a single speed.)

And they look super-clean too.  A single brake lever/cable is the only 'external' element on the bike.

Comment: You didn't answer the question though - why single speed rather than fixed? What prompted the choice (after 8 years, didn't you ever consider the option?)

Comment: @Unsliced: The question was why do people read single speed bikes.  Fixed bikes are a kind of single speed.  The question is not comparing them.

Comment: I can see the ambiguity in the phrase construction, but given that the fixie question was explicitly cited, I assumed that the basis for this question would be around why people chose un-fixed single-speed, as the why-fixed was answered elsewhere?

Comment: @Unsliced: Sorry, I disagree with your interpretation of the question.  While I agree that this question was informed by the ‘Why ride fixed?’ question, I still view this as a separate and independent question.  If the _intended_ question was ‘Why ride single speed rather than fixed?’ then that should be the title, not ‘Why ride single speed?’

Comment: +1 I've been saving up to buy a 24" bmx inspired bike like this one http://www.sundaybikes.com/catalog/plus-4/ then I could go on "bike rides" with the family...I'd never bother with anything but single speed.

Comment: having a ratcheting hub is nice.

Comment: Maybe the question is ambiguous @David HAust, but the questioner, in a comment to http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/why-ride-a-fixed-gear-bike explicitly says that this question is to answer "why no freewheel?" ...

Comment: The one word answer to single speed vs fixed gear is "coasting".

Comment: @Unsliced: As I said before, if 'why no freewheel?' is the question then the title of the question should be changed to that. Are users really expected to go trawling through the OPs comments on other questions to distill the 'real' meaning of this question? I don't care what the question is, let's just make it clear and obvious, especially to users who are viewing this question in isolation and not part of a larger conversation.

Comment: I just have to point out that riding single-speed with only one brake should very much be discouraged. You should have two redundant braking systems.

Comment: The only answer contains one hint, one honest reason to the question 'Why'. I ride them because the way they look. 'They look super clean' They look cool, ie they are fashionable.

Answer (score 6):

Single Speeds are about a ride more challenging, not in the sense of being harder physically, but more of a chess game than a test of leg and lung strength...knowing when to pause, maybe even almost track stand to get that extra oomph you need to attack that loose steep section. No gears to help you, just your mind to adapt your riding style to the constraints of the bike. The rear end of the SS is SO much lighter. And I don't put  any extra weight there either, the rear end is unsprung weight, and it rolls better the lighter it is. A geared bike's derailleur and long chain acts as a damper when you try to lift the back end...the SS pulls up willingly, like a BMX bike. Momentum is REALLY your friend on a SS, you have all the incentive to attack at the top of the hill and keep off the brake, since you may be going too fast to pedal back up to speed. Technique pays off, especially in steep sections where you may need to stand up and know how to keep the rear wheel planted. I enjoy climbing standing up, pulling on the bars at about 5RPM, while my buddy next to me grinds away on his granny ring. Having a light and simple bike helps me afford better parts, which last longer. No expensive cassettes to wear out folks! And personally, the SS makes me feel like a kid!

Comment: Bravo for an excellent and honest answer. To paraphrase 'I ride a single speed bicycles because I enjoy the challenge.' Most of these answers are analogous to giving reasons to why they have a square wheel on a wheel barrel and coming up with reasons  and circumstances to why and how a square wheel is superior to a round wheel.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the process of converting my 18 speed 1989 Peugeot Sahara into a single speed. It's going to be a purely commuting bike, although it was originally intended as an "ATB" (the first incarnation of today's mountain bikes).

I agree with David, there is more of a connection to the road, a lot of that feeling being down to, I think, the slimmed down simlplicity of the bike - less tech between rider and road.

There are fitness benefits too with just having one gear, although I wouldn't want to take it on trips of any great length.

Comment: Also, in the fixed vs. singlespeed pitched battle, for me it's down to being able to free wheel and having the luxury of brakes!

Answer (score 3):

If I had a single speed instead of fixed gear, I could do one thing that I really miss:

Bunny hop a curb.  That's something I've had to do more than once on a regular road bike just to avoid cars and it's something I do all the time on a variety of bikes just for convenience.  For the life of me, I can't do it at more than a crawl with a fixie.   I can shift weight over a pothole or the like, that's not too bad, but getting airborne is impossible for me.

The Fixie keeps me off some of the types of locations I rode all the time in college: extensive sidewalks, railroad tracks, potholes, etc...   Not a problem where I live, but it would have been years ago.

Comment: I agree big time. I love riding fixed but it's almost impossible to get air to clear gutters, potholes, seams in concrete paths, etc

Comment: Timing - Get yourself ready so that whichever foot is the front foot (at the launch moment) is still and give the back foot a big lift.  You'll need cleats or toe cages or straps to lift the pedal.  Its all timing, where your front foot is the fulcrum and the back foot is the power, and the cranks are the lever.    I've never managed to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I can see both sides of the argument for geared bicycles vs. non geared bicycles.
On one hand, you have more versatility in terrain/speed/ease of pedaling, while on the other you have the beauty of simplicity.
To answer your question, many SS (single speed) riders argue that because you only have one gear, you have much less maintenance with your bicycle. This means you don't have shift cables to lube or adjust/tune, and you don't have to worry about damaging a derailleur as there isn't one. A damaged derailleur is often a result of dropping a bicycle or banging it against something. You also have the simplicity of not having to choose between various gears. For a rider newer to cycling, this can be beneficial as you are much less likely to "drop" a chain off the chain ring, or be stuck in between gears, or end up in a gear that is either too high or low.
The only maintenance one might foresee-ably have is cleaning and relubing the chain every other week to keep it in good working order, and checking the chain tension to make sure that the chain stays on properly. 
An SS set up can also be helpful in strength training and cadence training, as it is likely that one won't have it geared perfect for every slope. It may be too big to climb hills easier, therefore strength training, and it may be too small to go all too fast on flat ground, therefore cadence training. 
I hope that this was enough of an objective opinion for you to make a decision

Answer (score 3):

I rode a single speed bike in a 24hr enduro mountain bike race. Out of a group of 5 friends I was the only one to finish as all their bikes broke, generally from the rear mech getting clogged up with mud jamming and getting ripped off the frame. Much better for reliability!!

When I was resting in the paddocks the number of people I saw carrying their bikes past with their rear mechs hanging was quite surprising.

Answer (score 2):

It is my opinion that fixed geared bikes can almost never be as fast as a freewheel bicycle, unless the rider has a front brake to rely on for stopping power, instead of his or her legs. Fixed riders have to monitor their speed in order to gauge stopping time and gear up for the strain of slowing down by pedals. Because of this, a smaller gear is preferred on this type of bike. If the bike has a brake, a larger gear can be put on and the need to prepare to stop won't be as great, and neither will the strain. More fixed gear riders should consider this but because a lot of people are attracted to the total simplicity of the bike in the first place, it seems like a sellout to add a brake to your fixed gear. Seen as pussy-ass to some. Also wearing a helmet is pretty pussy-ass to these people too, but to me, going slow is most pussy-ass of all. Also in this area, riding fixed no brakes would require a monthly purchase of a replacement rear tire (on descents, stopping in time forces riders to skid the back wheel across the pavement which wears the tire to shreds).

I ride freewheel because my bottom bracket is low enough to cause my pedals to strike the ground on moderate to pronounced turns, and I do not wish to sacrifice speed. The single speed free wheel bike is gratifying in 52/16 or 15, but a smaller gear like 42/16 Is annoying. You don't go as fast. You have no reason then to refrain from going fixed and ditching the brakes. Where I live there are hills and on the larger gear I was forced to keep a grueling momentum to top the hills and draft on large vehicles. I am terribly fit because of it, and have been lucky enough to avoid lingering soreness and neck pain. It was fun, and incredibly fast. You had to be fast in that gear. It is a great setup. However, I got a job pulling a forty pound trailer and had to put a 42t chainring on my bike and a rear caliper. It's good for pulling. I can steam up the hills no problem, and the added caliper is a life saver for sure with all the weight. BUT, the rest of the time, the 150 miles a month I ride off the clock, is weird because the spinning is faster with less speed and more pain to my knees. Your legs become toned and fit for powerful, cadenced, pedal strokes in the high gear, and when yo move lower, the increased cadence becomes a challenge to cope with. I seems you're working harder to go slower. Pussy-ass indeed. So here's what I'd say, pick a gear you rock in, and keep in mind that if you go fixed: you compromise speed and safety by using a small gear without brakes: you compromise safety but not speed if you have a big gear and no brake: and with a big gear and a brake you compromise nothing.

P.S. the dropout direction on a bike doesn't matter. its the way the rear wheel is mounted onto the bicycle. bolts are safer, but too tight can put stress on the steel, so a quick release wheel with a chain tensioner like the surly tuggnut or the redline cross mountain version, is my ideal choice. Keep in mind that it is unsafe to add a derailleur mount chain tensioner on a fixed gear and a fixed gear can almost NEVER be successful if the wheel is mounted onto fork ends, as many high end race bikes have, without the magic gear. Which is extremely hard to find.

Comment: Nobody says you have to not have breaks to go fixie. I my fixie I have both a front and a rear brake. The advantage of a fixed is that it forces your feet/legs to move in proper cadence and not change it up too much.  I have the brakes for exactly the reason you mention. With a decent gear on the bike, it's almost impossible to actually skid the rear tire, and it takes quite a distance to stop just using the drive train.

Answer (score 2):

ride single speed because its fun! if you are a fixie person a fixie is the bike for you. if you live in hilly areas, its not a problem. you dont need to be ripped, im 13 and i live on a hill. if you really are a fixie person, it wont matter. you can either get brakes for downhills or if youre willing to due to the fact that braking ruins the paint on the rims, you will walk down hills. it all depends on the person. if youre not willing to but you love fixies, you can buy a road bike and customize it to look how you want, just like a fixie

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles.SE. Could you clarify on what exactly a "fixie person" is? How can someone determine whether they are one?

Comment: What a frank, candid, and honest answer and IMO this is the best answer. People ride single speed simply because it's fun not for some other dubious technical reason. It takes a 13-year-old to admit the emperor has no clothes.

Answer (score 2):

**Cost.**

I ride year-round in Oregon in the woods.  In the sunshine (yes, it happens more than you'd expect in Oregon) I ride my full-suspension bike with many gears.  In the winter, I ride my rigid, single-speed bike.

The rigid, single-speed is much easier to clean, and when parts do wear out, they are much cheaper to replace.  Plus there are many fewer parts to wear out.  Riding in the woods in the winter puts a **lot** of wear on a bike.

A quick search shows the following prices:

- BMX chain: $5-$10    10-speed chain: $20-$40
- BMX free hub: $20-$25, 10-speed cassette: $30-$60
- no derailleurs, 10-speed derailleur: $15 (front) $50 (rear)
- no shift cables, new cables/housing: $15

Plus there's the mechanic cost (and time).  I can do the work myself, but I'm dog slow, so I take it to the shop - and that adds more $ to the picture.

etc.

*Of course those prices are just ball-park prices, you can find 10-speed parts for less than some single-speed parts, but you'd be getting low-end 10-speed parts and higher end single-speed parts.*

*Edited to remove costs not associated with gearing.*

Comment: An interesting perspective, but you're confusing the issue by mixing in suspension. 90% of your upkeep costs are suspension-specific, no?

Comment: $400 for "fork upkeep"?  I'll admit that, after a dozen years, I spent $250 getting all my bearings repacked, cables replaced, brake pads replaced, new cassette and two new rings, but I doubt that $20 of that could be charged to the fork bearings, and there was no suspension to worry about.

Comment: Edited to remove the suspension costs.  They are significant, but it's true they have nothing to do with the choice of single speed in general.

Answer (score 1):

I think they have the benefit of looking as good as a fixie, and being pretty much as light, without the need for all that silly pedalling downhill.

Comment: If it's not fixed, it's broken ;)

Comment: Sadly I think this is the correct answer. They look hipster like a fixie without being difficult to ride.

Answer (score 1):

Because you only need one gear when it's the perfect ratio (44/16).

Comment: I'd say 46/16, or maybe even 48/16, but the 48 especially would depend on where you lived...

Comment: Meh, if you wanted to go real fast maybe. I like making it easier to stop and go.

Comment: Ha, more like 36/19, there's no chance of climbing the trails around here with 44/16.  (yes, mountain bikes are bikes too...)

Answer (score 1):

I ride a single speed because I'm lazy. The less mass you take up a hill, the less work you do – at least in theory. The trick is having the best single gearing for the average hills you encounter. The other trick is not being in a hurry when you're on the flat sections. A good medium gearing or medium tall gearing is all I need. When I moved from a hilly town to one that had no hills except for bridges, I put on a bigger front sprocket to tall things up a bit and I was happy again.

Another thing I do is have two single speeds. One has skinnier tires and is geared taller for higher speeds and the better cooling effect of having more air moving past me on hot summer days. That's my cheap bright red Schwinn Madison. The other bike is my Surly Steamroller which has fatter tires and geared lower and runs a coaster brake for completely silent running at night. I'm grateful that they finally have headlights that are powerful enough to actually see where you're going on a bicycle at night.

In addition, I like my one-speeds because I am so familiar with the single gearing that they have, I always know my acceleration potential at any given speed. This is good information to have when dodging cars and trucks in city traffic where I do all my cycling.

Of course there's also the maintenance thing. When the bike has to be just about perfect before you'll ride it, having a single speed makes life a bit easier.

That's my story and I'm sticking to it. After fifty years or so of bicycling on a daily basis, a guy gets set in his ways.

Answer (score 1):

Because I don't like riding fixed downhill.

Also, because though 10 percent of the time hills are murder & 10 percent of the time I spin out, the other 80 percent of the time the thing just flies!

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate a bit more. In its current form your answer is quite unclear. For example I guess that in your mind you compare riding a single speed to riding a fixie and not to riding a "normal" multi-gear bike, which is an important point to understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoy riding singlespeed. Much more relaxing, you don't have to think about changing gear, you just pedal, and if you want to go faster, you pedal faster.

It's much faster too, heaps less friction, according to wikipedia it's 10-15% more efficient. I run a 52-20 and it's good up til about 45-50 kph. Lots less maintainance, lighter, quieter. Looks much cleaner too. I really like the non maintance side of things. They are actually faster on the flat.

Comment: If you were referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_gearing#Efficiency, it certainly doesn't state that SS is 10-15% more efficient than a bike with derailleurs.

Comment: Seriously? 50kph on a 52-20 is 153rpm. My summer rig is 48-16 and while I can do 50+kph, it isn't comfortable. If you can get to 150rpm, chapeau.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing something that backs up the "heaps less friction" statement. The only extra friction that I can think of on a geared bike is from the two pulleys in the rear derailleur. Maybe a little more from the lateral movement of the chain, but I can't imagine that either amount to much in comparison with all the other moving parts.

Answer (score 0):

30 of the last 40 years (10 years off due to illness & injuries) cycling as a commuter, racing or combo of both.  Bit of a heart defect, too old, too slow, too out of form to consider getting back into any form of racing.  But I like cycling.  Cost to get the '95 LiteSpeed refitted was more than budgeted for cycling.  Less expensive alternative was a quality FGSS. Running single-speed due to the hilly terrain I ride on. 42x18 gearing.  Bit over geared on some of the climbs, under geared on the descents. Spinning away on the flats 19mph give or take 1 mph.  Downhills would be tough running fixed. SS means spinning out at 27-29mph and then freewheeling. Rural area. Hipsters? We have old hippies & red necks.

Bottom Line: 1. inexpensive, 2. simple maintenance, 3. Fun