# Is it possible to add speeds to single-speed bike?

Tags: single-speed

I found this cool cheap single-speed bike on amazon http://www.amazon.de/Fixie-Singlespeed-Viking-Farben-Auswahl/dp/B00BCKQ8AS/ref=lp_235171011_1_1?s=sports&ie=UTF8&qid=1422793944&sr=1-1

However my problem with it is that it is single speed & I would like to have 27 speeds. Is it possible to do that manually? i.e. to buy speeds and add it to the bike? I would why they didn't do it themselves!

Comment: It's possible but not practical.  You could add a multi-speed hub, eg, but it would be less satisfactory than the purpose-built bike and cost more.  Or, on that bike you could probably add a rear derailer.  But you'd also need cable and shifters, and the cost of hub, derailer, shifters, cable as "replacement" parts would be as much as the bike costs.  I have to believe that there are several multi-speed "road" bikes available for only a little more money (since bike assemblers don't have to pay "list" for parts).

Comment: 27 speeds is a lot of speeds. Most bikes with 27 speeds don't really have 27 different speeds, as there are a lot of combinations which are basically the same as other combinations. Even pro racers only have 22 speeds, again with some overlap. 7 or 8 speeds provides plenty of range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a 27 speed bike then buy one.  It is not cheaper to add speeds to a single speed or fixie bike.  Lots of stuff is not compatible including axle spacing and real wheel.

Comment: what is the value of a single-speed bike? I don't get it why they exist. Any idea?! I believe it is very difficult to live with a single-speed bike. I can't imagine going up a hill with it or a steep road :/

Comment: A single speed is simple and pure.  It has a following.

Comment: @JackTwain that comment spawns a whole new question.....but it looks like someone beat you to it! [Why ride a single-speed bike?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/why-ride-a-single-speed-bike)

Comment: single speed is cheap, light, less to break less to fix